# Xcode - Error creating LLDB target

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, lldb, beta

I'm getting this error whenever I build in XCode 6 beta 4. It seems to be making my app insanely slow.

> **Warning:** Error creating LLDB target at path
>   '/***/***/***/***.app'- using an empty LLDB target which
>   can cause slow memory reads from remote devices.

What exactly does this mean and how do I fix it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am getting this issue too.  It is making my app unresponsive

Comment: The top answer for this helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25761447/error-creating-lldb-target-at-path-xcode-6-gm-seed

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Did you use `Architectures=$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)` and run your app on a 64 bit device? (iPhone 5S or iPhone 5S simulator)

Apple seems to be stricter with apps which don't support 64bit. So if there is no specific reason, I think it's better to include arm64 in your build architecture

> NOTE ABOUT 64-BIT ARCHITECTURE
>
> An app extension target must include the arm64 architecture in its Architectures build settings or it will be rejected by the App Store. Xcode includes this architecture with its “Standard architectures” setting when you create a new app extension target.
>
> If your containing app target links to an embedded framework, the app must also include the arm64 architecture or it will be rejected by the App Store.
>
> For more information about 64-bit development, see 64-Bit Transition Guide for Cocoa Touch or 64-Bit Transition Guide for Cocoa, depending on your target platform.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionCreation.html

Comment: In particular I think the issue is that you need to support the native architecture of the device you're targeting.

Comment: ok to be fair that documentation is about app EXTENSIONS and not apps.

Comment: for me the issue was in the 2nd paragraph. I have many nested projects in my main project, some of which were not including arm64

Comment: You also have to include it in 'Valid Architectures' build setting.

Answer (score 9):

This warning is solved by changing Build Settings :

1. Select Project -> Build Settings
2. Change **'Architectures' to 'Standard architectures (armv7, arm64) - $(ARCHS_STANDARD)'**
   [image: Step 2]
3. This will prompt an alert stating iOS 5.1.1 and above are supported. Click **'Change Deployment Target to 5.1.1'**

[image: Step 3]

4. Repeat steps for Target (if not changed automatically)

[image: Step 4]

Also, this is preferred build setting since Apple is forcing developers to build apps on 64 but architecture. [Apple document Link](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=12172014b)

Answer (score 4):

Double Check Build Settings => Valid Architectures for both Project and Target.

Mine used to say: **arm64 armv7 i386** (The one causing the error was i386)

I replaced it to :  **arm64 armv7**

I hope that helps.

Comment: Hey @wilforeal why you replaced with arm64 armv7 arm64?

Comment: @wilforeal you have arm64 twice on your list.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to change Build Active Architecture Only (`ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH`) to YES for the Debug configuration.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 6.4 , Swift 1.2. I had to edit both the Project and Target to the correct arm verisons (arm64, armv7 and armv7s). Take a look:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My "Architectures" included arm64 but I had to add arm64 to "Valid Architectures" in the target.

Comment: Damm, now I have a zillion "Conversion loses precision" warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Use `file` to check the archicture of the build executable. The build folder can be located with the **Product** > **Show Build Folder in Finder** menu.

```bash
pwd
# …path/to/Build
cd Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ExampleName.app

file ExampleName
# Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64

### x86_64 can raise the empty LLDB target error when debugging
### iOS in the Simulator on an Apple Silicon computer.
```

The following settings resolved the `…using an empty LLDB target…` error for Xcode 15.2 and the associated iPhone Simulator:

*.xcodeproj Settings*

| Title | Name | Debug | Release |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Architectures | `ARCHS` | default: `$(ARCHS_STANDARD)` | default: `$(ARCHS_STANDARD)` |
| Excluded Architectures | `EXCLUDED_ARCHS` | unset | unset |
| Build Active Architectures Only | `ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH` | Yes | default: No |

*CocoaPods Podfile*

```rb
### other: `ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH` = YES only for `*Debug*` configurations
if config.name.include?("Debug")
    config.build_settings["ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH"] = "NO"
end
```

*debug.xcconfig*

As FYI, the `ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH` setting can be added to `*.xcconfig` files for both implementation and documentation purposes.

```ini
// Resolve "Error creating LLDB target … using an empty LLDB target…"
ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH = YES
```