# Error creating LLDB target at path, Xcode 6 GM seed,the screen stuck

Tags: ios, xcode6

I'm getting this error sometimes when I build in Xcode 6 GM Seed.

I had the following error:

```
Warning: Error creating LLDB target at path '.....'- using an empty LLDB target which can cause slow memory reads from remote devices.
```

Then my app become very slow on some page;and what's worse is that whenever my code response the method of [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]... the screen stuck and the warning following;

I don't konw why;
What exactly does this mean and how do I fix it?

PS:It seems like the xcode doesn't create the .plist file when the method of [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]... been used;I open the sandbox and I can't find nothing in the related files.

Comment: I believe this problem is addressed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25088252/xcode-error-creating-lldb-target In particular, I think the solution is to make sure you build for the architecture of the device you're running the app on.

Comment: Question is that I use the iphone 5 simulator,the warining has gone;but when I goto the breakpoint of [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]... the app stuck;but the data has been stored;By the way,where can I find the .plist file created by [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] set...(xcode 5,it's in the file of preference)? @ThomasW

Comment: Most likely your project settings aren't supporting 64 bit architecture. iPhone 5 is 32-bit, so the warning doesn't show in that case.