# XCode 7: Error creating LLDB target

Tags: ios, xcode, ios9, xcode7

I'm getting the following warning in XCode 7 (7A220) on an iOS9 simulator:

> **Warning:** Error creating LLDB target at path '***.app'- using an empty LLDB target which can cause slow memory reads from remote devices.

A project has been previously built for iOS8 in XCode 6 without any warnings and also I've checked out all similar topics on SO, like this one:
[Xcode - Error creating LLDB target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25088252/xcode-error-creating-lldb-target)

But all they are boiled down to the one thing: "Change 'Architectures' to 'Standard architectures (armv7, arm64) - $(ARCHS_STANDARD)'". This point has already been successfully performed in the previous version of a project in Xcode 6 (and all existent topics have to do with the aforementioned version):

[image]

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved by adding `arm64` to `Valid Architectures` as well. More about the difference between `Architectures` and `Valid Architectures` is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12701209/3242031).

Answer (score 1):

With XCode 8 and iOS 10 you may run into this very same problem. I got the error when building an app originally created in XCode 6 or 7 for the simulator, in debug. My old setting was Project -> Architectures -> **ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH** -> Debug - yes / Release - no. Setting the value for Debug to No solved it.  No idea who or what added ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH, but there you go.