# NSInvalidArgumentException crash for iPad Pro Sim but not for other iPad Sim

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, crash, ios-simulator

I have an app in the App Store that I haven't maintained since iOS7's release and getting some requests to refresh it.

I am attempting to get it updated so that it runs on latest iOS 8 and all current iOS iPad devices.

When I test run in sim for any non-Pro iPad simulators, it works. But when I test run on iPad Pro, it crashes. Here are the details.

In `main.m`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    // crashes on this line (i know this is not that useful)
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

Output window (apologize for the verbosity here, but didn't want to leave out anything potentially useful):

```
Warning: Error creating LLDB target at path '/Users/pubnubcvconover/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Stats-Pad-coxczetuymekypghmygwqysiqulp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Lacrosse-Stats.app'- using an empty LLDB target which can cause slow memory reads from remote devices.
2016-02-28 16:59:43.301 Lacrosse-Stats[4205:95840] ADBannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError:The operation couldn’t be completed. (ADErrorDomain error 3.)
2016-02-28 16:59:43.303 Lacrosse-Stats[4205:95840] Ran setTeams
2016-02-28 16:59:44.222 Lacrosse-Stats[4205:95840] CoreData: error: -addPersistentStoreWithType:Binary configuration:(null) URL:file:///Users/pubnubcvconover/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/91D7C4F6-34CA-4761-913F-C0B50E753469/data/Containers/Data/Application/ED789ADC-FB9C-43E2-8FDE-E02D80DD43E6/Documents/Stats_Pad.bin options:{
    NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption = 1;
    NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption = 1;
} ... returned error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134130 "(null)" UserInfo={URL=file:///Users/pubnubcvconover/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/91D7C4F6-34CA-4761-913F-C0B50E753469/data/Containers/Data/Application/ED789ADC-FB9C-43E2-8FDE-E02D80DD43E6/Documents/Stats_Pad.bin, metadata={
    NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 641;
    NSStoreModelVersionHashes =     {
        "field_conditions" = <1a8f23c4 a8f9f08a 7504bd89 b6c608df 89106202 f9c81f02 2441924c 12245334>;
        "field_layout" = <da72d767 8f4c3614 fe56ab18 37905a4e b7890395 03515759 46c20c7b 78cbb6cb>;
        game = <8f8c1e3b 595416df 4164209d 35268bfd e4f41bf7 aed776a9 3bcfe86a dea6fe6a>;
        gender = <bcdc57c3 7ad84924 40c67207 735167f4 e773c4b8 6fc53316 b9fe0220 4e53fad8>;
        levels = <7aa35176 e55edff3 7ac01812 5cc17a05 60013487 92196c1d 366a437b a108a9ef>;
        p = <593e105a 8ce080f6 aeb0081d 250039e3 6363b0a0 380fc096 6d18653e da7c1612>;
        "p_event" = <acf2f48d 3d5ef365 6e6153a2 268ab4d2 9c4776ed 6165781e f86c0bbc 5b8bfe90>;
        "p_type" = <36aaae5d db755d03 9a66e7b0 703ca8bf 5de4210a c6c9e8e3 ea77b8f4 6fd8f8fb>;
        penalty = <a8ff8a90 08434fec 24caa525 b16972eb f9a35891 54945888 e68d6faf 7d7aea9f>;
        "penalty_event" = <09ef67b3 238a32e0 1a2526d6 82374563 c7275b43 a11d26df fa8447b4 ac7f1175>;
        "penalty_type" = <3cdcaf67 0748f85e 0b300ba0 4119f7c2 04cf6a39 1b836ec8 5850f3e6 3662e8ff>;
        player = <9d572c6d 15c11f5f 5d4aa3d0 10b75ea3 fa3dd352 1f89a53f f3a3f02e b3d1a4c1>;
        position = <89407c79 8f0655a6 550666a3 9e87738d fb985882 5ae70c3a 9ca51fd7 50b24a94>;
        roster = <34471eca 339a9ab4 ed86afc9 727c17c3 6117156b e726de09 97c979f2 d4272814>;
        rules = <0f7d4bc6 5b82e1ee 6b3e9c3d 2c73ea62 78c6bbbb bb02b6c0 0bdc8a5e 2bc1d22d>;
        statistic = <b92a539d 6329e839 d24a80ef e4006a28 3ee3cf68 5cbe1342 5a79f9c7 760f3ffe>;
        "statistic_event" = <2d6d03bf 53f05b88 ddc692bc ab805dea 210dc3cb 93ea04e9 c2005fe1 d9f817d3>;
        "statistic_type" = <84c5603e 008cdbc3 411c883d a0ac485b 160c35c8 f5ce7394 0fc06d2d c72ece9d>;
        team = <97de1350 f685c550 8de940e6 e0c6d8fc f2cd1b80 94725d1b 535f0ff3 13474223>;
        "weather_conditions" = <23bce103 1dbe85b6 c7b92d66 69c2d334 34baf747 8ae60dcc dee2b5e0 b739bf31>;
    };
    NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
    NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =     (
        ""
    );
    NSStoreType = Binary;
    NSStoreUUID = "829124BC-14FB-43C5-A845-A630BB9603E9";
    "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
}, reason=Can't find model for source store} with userInfo dictionary {
    URL = "file:///Users/pubnubcvconover/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/91D7C4F6-34CA-4761-913F-C0B50E753469/data/Containers/Data/Application/ED789ADC-FB9C-43E2-8FDE-E02D80DD43E6/Documents/Stats_Pad.bin";
    metadata =     {
        NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 641;
        NSStoreModelVersionHashes =         {
            "field_conditions" = <1a8f23c4 a8f9f08a 7504bd89 b6c608df 89106202 f9c81f02 2441924c 12245334>;
            "field_layout" = <da72d767 8f4c3614 fe56ab18 37905a4e b7890395 03515759 46c20c7b 78cbb6cb>;
            game = <8f8c1e3b 595416df 4164209d 35268bfd e4f41bf7 aed776a9 3bcfe86a dea6fe6a>;
            gender = <bcdc57c3 7ad84924 40c67207 735167f4 e773c4b8 6fc53316 b9fe0220 4e53fad8>;
            levels = <7aa35176 e55edff3 7ac01812 5cc17a05 60013487 92196c1d 366a437b a108a9ef>;
            p = <593e105a 8ce080f6 aeb0081d 250039e3 6363b0a0 380fc096 6d18653e da7c1612>;
            "p_event" = <acf2f48d 3d5ef365 6e6153a2 268ab4d2 9c4776ed 6165781e f86c0bbc 5b8bfe90>;
            "p_type" = <36aaae5d db755d03 9a66e7b0 703ca8bf 5de4210a c6c9e8e3 ea77b8f4 6fd8f8fb>;
            penalty = <a8ff8a90 08434fec 24caa525 b16972eb f9a35891 54945888 e68d6faf 7d7aea9f>;
            "penalty_event" = <09ef67b3 238a32e0 1a2526d6 82374563 c7275b43 a11d26df fa8447b4 ac7f1175>;
            "penalty_type" = <3cdcaf67 0748f85e 0b300ba0 4119f7c2 04cf6a39 1b836ec8 5850f3e6 3662e8ff>;
            player = <9d572c6d 15c11f5f 5d4aa3d0 10b75ea3 fa3dd352 1f89a53f f3a3f02e b3d1a4c1>;
            position = <89407c79 8f0655a6 550666a3 9e87738d fb985882 5ae70c3a 9ca51fd7 50b24a94>;
            roster = <34471eca 339a9ab4 ed86afc9 727c17c3 6117156b e726de09 97c979f2 d4272814>;
            rules = <0f7d4bc6 5b82e1ee 6b3e9c3d 2c73ea62 78c6bbbb bb02b6c0 0bdc8a5e 2bc1d22d>;
            statistic = <b92a539d 6329e839 d24a80ef e4006a28 3ee3cf68 5cbe1342 5a79f9c7 760f3ffe>;
            "statistic_event" = <2d6d03bf 53f05b88 ddc692bc ab805dea 210dc3cb 93ea04e9 c2005fe1 d9f817d3>;
            "statistic_type" = <84c5603e 008cdbc3 411c883d a0ac485b 160c35c8 f5ce7394 0fc06d2d c72ece9d>;
            team = <97de1350 f685c550 8de940e6 e0c6d8fc f2cd1b80 94725d1b 535f0ff3 13474223>;
            "weather_conditions" = <23bce103 1dbe85b6 c7b92d66 69c2d334 34baf747 8ae60dcc dee2b5e0 b739bf31>;
        };
        NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
        NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =         (
            ""
        );
        NSStoreType = Binary;
        NSStoreUUID = "829124BC-14FB-43C5-A845-A630BB9603E9";
        "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
    };
    reason = "Can't find model for source store";
}
2016-02-28 16:59:44.223 Lacrosse-Stats[4205:95840] CoreData: annotation: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator's current model hashes are {
    "field_conditions" = <1a8f23c4 a8f9f08a 7504bd89 b6c608df 89106202 f9c81f02 2441924c 12245334>;
    "field_layout" = <da72d767 8f4c3614 fe56ab18 37905a4e b7890395 03515759 46c20c7b 78cbb6cb>;
    game = <7c5aa182 4171414b b6bcfb04 358894d8 95dd0b1f b32ba46d 440ac807 17a00b19>;
    gender = <bcdc57c3 7ad84924 40c67207 735167f4 e773c4b8 6fc53316 b9fe0220 4e53fad8>;
    levels = <7aa35176 e55edff3 7ac01812 5cc17a05 60013487 92196c1d 366a437b a108a9ef>;
    p = <593e105a 8ce080f6 aeb0081d 250039e3 6363b0a0 380fc096 6d18653e da7c1612>;
    "p_event" = <acf2f48d 3d5ef365 6e6153a2 268ab4d2 9c4776ed 6165781e f86c0bbc 5b8bfe90>;
    "p_type" = <36aaae5d db755d03 9a66e7b0 703ca8bf 5de4210a c6c9e8e3 ea77b8f4 6fd8f8fb>;
    penalty = <a8ff8a90 08434fec 24caa525 b16972eb f9a35891 54945888 e68d6faf 7d7aea9f>;
    "penalty_event" = <09ef67b3 238a32e0 1a2526d6 82374563 c7275b43 a11d26df fa8447b4 ac7f1175>;
    "penalty_type" = <3cdcaf67 0748f85e 0b300ba0 4119f7c2 04cf6a39 1b836ec8 5850f3e6 3662e8ff>;
    player = <4918d629 1aacc24b 59f5942f 0a0222ea 72edf9c7 18d74c0b ec0de756 5ad19d4a>;
    position = <89407c79 8f0655a6 550666a3 9e87738d fb985882 5ae70c3a 9ca51fd7 50b24a94>;
    roster = <34471eca 339a9ab4 ed86afc9 727c17c3 6117156b e726de09 97c979f2 d4272814>;
    rules = <0f7d4bc6 5b82e1ee 6b3e9c3d 2c73ea62 78c6bbbb bb02b6c0 0bdc8a5e 2bc1d22d>;
    statistic = <b92a539d 6329e839 d24a80ef e4006a28 3ee3cf68 5cbe1342 5a79f9c7 760f3ffe>;
    "statistic_event" = <f8cecbe6 338d513d fc123e58 0cc3c8c6 15295759 91a7eb52 af6f5603 c26f571a>;
    "statistic_type" = <84c5603e 008cdbc3 411c883d a0ac485b 160c35c8 f5ce7394 0fc06d2d c72ece9d>;
    team = <214fad10 4519c1a5 e799b6ec aefc9adf 16dcae30 b09a01c6 00c4a89d cb113e16>;
    "weather_conditions" = <23bce103 1dbe85b6 c7b92d66 69c2d334 34baf747 8ae60dcc dee2b5e0 b739bf31>;
}
2016-02-28 16:59:44.225 Lacrosse-Stats[4205:95840] Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134130 "(null)" UserInfo={URL=file:///Users/pubnubcvconover/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/91D7C4F6-34CA-4761-913F-C0B50E753469/data/Containers/Data/Application/ED789ADC-FB9C-43E2-8FDE-E02D80DD43E6/Documents/Stats_Pad.bin, metadata={
    NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 641;
    NSStoreModelVersionHashes =     {
        "field_conditions" = <1a8f23c4 a8f9f08a 7504bd89 b6c608df 89106202 f9c81f02 2441924c 12245334>;
        "field_layout" = <da72d767 8f4c3614 fe56ab18 37905a4e b7890395 03515759 46c20c7b 78cbb6cb>;
        game = <8f8c1e3b 595416df 4164209d 35268bfd e4f41bf7 aed776a9 3bcfe86a dea6fe6a>;
        gender = <bcdc57c3 7ad84924 40c67207 735167f4 e773c4b8 6fc53316 b9fe0220 4e53fad8>;
        levels = <7aa35176 e55edff3 7ac01812 5cc17a05 60013487 92196c1d 366a437b a108a9ef>;
        p = <593e105a 8ce080f6 aeb0081d 250039e3 6363b0a0 380fc096 6d18653e da7c1612>;
        "p_event" = <acf2f48d 3d5ef365 6e6153a2 268ab4d2 9c4776ed 6165781e f86c0bbc 5b8bfe90>;
        "p_type" = <36aaae5d db755d03 9a66e7b0 703ca8bf 5de4210a c6c9e8e3 ea77b8f4 6fd8f8fb>;
        penalty = <a8ff8a90 08434fec 24caa525 b16972eb f9a35891 54945888 e68d6faf 7d7aea9f>;
        "penalty_event" = <09ef67b3 238a32e0 1a2526d6 82374563 c7275b43 a11d26df fa8447b4 ac7f1175>;
        "penalty_type" = <3cdcaf67 0748f85e 0b300ba0 4119f7c2 04cf6a39 1b836ec8 5850f3e6 3662e8ff>;
        player = <9d572c6d 15c11f5f 5d4aa3d0 10b75ea3 fa3dd352 1f89a53f f3a3f02e b3d1a4c1>;
        position = <89407c79 8f0655a6 550666a3 9e87738d fb985882 5ae70c3a 9ca51fd7 50b24a94>;
        roster = <34471eca 339a9ab4 ed86afc9 727c17c3 6117156b e726de09 97c979f2 d4272814>;
        rules = <0f7d4bc6 5b82e1ee 6b3e9c3d 2c73ea62 78c6bbbb bb02b6c0 0bdc8a5e 2bc1d22d>;
        statistic = <b92a539d 6329e839 d24a80ef e4006a28 3ee3cf68 5cbe1342 5a79f9c7 760f3ffe>;
        "statistic_event" = <2d6d03bf 53f05b88 ddc692bc ab805dea 210dc3cb 93ea04e9 c2005fe1 d9f817d3>;
        "statistic_type" = <84c5603e 008cdbc3 411c883d a0ac485b 160c35c8 f5ce7394 0fc06d2d c72ece9d>;
        team = <97de1350 f685c550 8de940e6 e0c6d8fc f2cd1b80 94725d1b 535f0ff3 13474223>;
        "weather_conditions" = <23bce103 1dbe85b6 c7b92d66 69c2d334 34baf747 8ae60dcc dee2b5e0 b739bf31>;
    };
    NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
    NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =     (
        ""
    );
    NSStoreType = Binary;
    NSStoreUUID = "829124BC-14FB-43C5-A845-A630BB9603E9";
    "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
}, reason=Can't find model for source store}, {
    URL = "file:///Users/pubnubcvconover/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/91D7C4F6-34CA-4761-913F-C0B50E753469/data/Containers/Data/Application/ED789ADC-FB9C-43E2-8FDE-E02D80DD43E6/Documents/Stats_Pad.bin";
    metadata =     {
        NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 641;
        NSStoreModelVersionHashes =         {
            "field_conditions" = <1a8f23c4 a8f9f08a 7504bd89 b6c608df 89106202 f9c81f02 2441924c 12245334>;
            "field_layout" = <da72d767 8f4c3614 fe56ab18 37905a4e b7890395 03515759 46c20c7b 78cbb6cb>;
            game = <8f8c1e3b 595416df 4164209d 35268bfd e4f41bf7 aed776a9 3bcfe86a dea6fe6a>;
            gender = <bcdc57c3 7ad84924 40c67207 735167f4 e773c4b8 6fc53316 b9fe0220 4e53fad8>;
            levels = <7aa35176 e55edff3 7ac01812 5cc17a05 60013487 92196c1d 366a437b a108a9ef>;
            p = <593e105a 8ce080f6 aeb0081d 250039e3 6363b0a0 380fc096 6d18653e da7c1612>;
            "p_event" = <acf2f48d 3d5ef365 6e6153a2 268ab4d2 9c4776ed 6165781e f86c0bbc 5b8bfe90>;
            "p_type" = <36aaae5d db755d03 9a66e7b0 703ca8bf 5de4210a c6c9e8e3 ea77b8f4 6fd8f8fb>;
            penalty = <a8ff8a90 08434fec 24caa525 b16972eb f9a35891 54945888 e68d6faf 7d7aea9f>;
            "penalty_event" = <09ef67b3 238a32e0 1a2526d6 82374563 c7275b43 a11d26df fa8447b4 ac7f1175>;
            "penalty_type" = <3cdcaf67 0748f85e 0b300ba0 4119f7c2 04cf6a39 1b836ec8 5850f3e6 3662e8ff>;
            player = <9d572c6d 15c11f5f 5d4aa3d0 10b75ea3 fa3dd352 1f89a53f f3a3f02e b3d1a4c1>;
            position = <89407c79 8f0655a6 550666a3 9e87738d fb985882 5ae70c3a 9ca51fd7 50b24a94>;
            roster = <34471eca 339a9ab4 ed86afc9 727c17c3 6117156b e726de09 97c979f2 d4272814>;
            rules = <0f7d4bc6 5b82e1ee 6b3e9c3d 2c73ea62 78c6bbbb bb02b6c0 0bdc8a5e 2bc1d22d>;
            statistic = <b92a539d 6329e839 d24a80ef e4006a28 3ee3cf68 5cbe1342 5a79f9c7 760f3ffe>;
            "statistic_event" = <2d6d03bf 53f05b88 ddc692bc ab805dea 210dc3cb 93ea04e9 c2005fe1 d9f817d3>;
            "statistic_type" = <84c5603e 008cdbc3 411c883d a0ac485b 160c35c8 f5ce7394 0fc06d2d c72ece9d>;
            team = <97de1350 f685c550 8de940e6 e0c6d8fc f2cd1b80 94725d1b 535f0ff3 13474223>;
            "weather_conditions" = <23bce103 1dbe85b6 c7b92d66 69c2d334 34baf747 8ae60dcc dee2b5e0 b739bf31>;
        };
        NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
        NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =         (
            ""
        );
        NSStoreType = Binary;
        NSStoreUUID = "829124BC-14FB-43C5-A845-A630BB9603E9";
        "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
    };
    reason = "Can't find model for source store";
}
2016-02-28 16:59:44.228 Lacrosse-Stats[4205:95840] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'team''
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x03ae1a14 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x035a2e02 objc_exception_throw + 50
    2   CoreData                            0x0321c859 +[NSEntityDescription entityForName:inManagedObjectContext:] + 281
    3   Lacrosse-Stats                      0x001c3619 -[SPTeamsController setTeams] + 217
    4   Lacrosse-Stats                      0x001c4b55 -[SPTeamsController viewDidLoad] + 741
    5   UIKit                               0x01e8b2ae -[UIViewController _sendViewDidLoadWithAppearanceProxyObjectTaggingEnabled] + 44
    6   UIKit                               0x01e8fdce -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1384
    7   UIKit                               0x01edb9f9 -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 52
    8   UIKit                               0x01edc2b1 -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 421
    9   UIKit                               0x01edc458 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 145
    10  UIKit                               0x01edd854 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 1038
    11  UIKit                               0x01edeada -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 68
    12  UIKit                               0x020bac4a -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 252
    13  UIKit                               0x01d90008 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 810
    14  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x035b7059 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
    15  QuartzCore                          0x0111480a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 144
    16  QuartzCore                          0x011084ee _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 388
    17  QuartzCore                          0x01108352 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 26
    18  QuartzCore                          0x010fae8b _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 317
    19  QuartzCore                          0x0112ee03 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 561
    20  QuartzCore                          0x01130674 _ZN2CA11Transaction17flush_transactionEv + 50
    21  UIKit                               0x01ce6bf8 __84-[UIApplication _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke_2 + 111
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x039fb6e0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 16
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x039f1063 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 195
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x039f0798 __CFRunLoopRun + 1016
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x039f00e6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x039efefb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    27  GraphicsServices                    0x044b1664 GSEventRunModal + 192
    28  GraphicsServices                    0x044b14a1 GSEventRun + 104
    29  UIKit                               0x01cc3bfa UIApplicationMain + 160
    30  Lacrosse-Stats                      0x000ecab9 main + 121
    31  libdyld.dylib                       0x03f54a21 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Perhaps some architecture build setting I need to adjust? Been out of the iOS dev world for a couple years so not aware of all the details of all the changes - more just high level awareness of such things.

Comment: First, have you deleted Derived Data and run a clean?

Comment: The app has default data and I haven't explicitly deleted. It still runs on iPad sim, just not iPad Pro sim.

Comment: I'm saying you should try doing that. And to do that, delete ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Derived Data, and then in Xcode go Product -> Clean, then do the same thing with options held down.

Comment: OK, deleted that folder, did a Clean but still same result.

Answer (score 0):

I searched on the first error it prints (Error creating LLDB target) and found this: [Xcode - Error creating LLDB target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25088252/xcode-error-creating-lldb-target)

Comment: I follow the guidance there but nothing panned out.

Answer (score 0):

I asked an iOS Engineer that I work with and he nailed it in 5 seconds.

Menu Option for Simulator

```
Simulator > Reset Content and Setttings...
```

[image]

And thanks to those that provided input.