# Using an empty LLDB target which can cause slow memory reads from remote devices

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, lldb, xcode12

I am using Xcode 12 and I am getting an warning as below:

Warning: Error creating LLDB target at path '/Users/ABC/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/demowatchapp-blfzfuqxehfteaaofqpdlfuurtdr/Build/Products/Debug-watchsimulator/watchapp.app'- using an empty LLDB target which can cause slow memory reads from remote devices.

I have checked that there are solutions to this from xcode 6 as to change the architecture to arm64. I checked that as well in build settings and it is mentioned as standard architecture. I have read it as with new xode apple itself make it as standard architecture i.e arm64, armv7. So now not sure what is wrong. I have also checked that my iOS app, watch app and the extension all have the same architecture.

[image]

I have also checked below link which are not working for me:
[Xcode - Error creating LLDB target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25088252/xcode-error-creating-lldb-target)

Comment: Having the same problem...

Comment: Same problem for me, with Xcode 12.0.1 (12A7300). Not only that, but some tests that passed in Xcode 12.0.0 are now _crashing_, and I can't quit the test runner. If I leave Xcode running at the crash point, my entire computer appears to have restarted without warning when I come back.

Comment: @Nik Any luck on this issue?

Comment: @BijoyThangaraj Not yet bro, looking for the same.

Comment: Same with XCode 12.1 (12A7403), even after fresh reinstallation and projects cleanup. Releases notes from betas not mentioned this issue. Any clues about this issue will be appreciated from community. I'm worry about this and blocked...

Comment: Any luck with this issue?

Comment: Problem seems to have disappeared with XCode 12.2ß

Comment: I do still experience the issue in Xcode Version 12.2 (12B45b). It has not been resolved yet.

Comment: Still seeing error on Xcode Version 12.3 (12C33) with standalone watchOS app.

Comment: Same issue with Xcode 12.5.1...

Answer (score 4):

**My Xcode 12.2 settings:**
*I use OS BigSur release*

I found that the setting *Architectures>Build Active Architecture Only>Release* must be set to Yes

[image: Architectures>Build Active Architecture Only>Release]

Comment: Just want to say that building for all architectures will cause rejection when uploading to App Store. For more information, see: https://medium.com/macoclock/deep-drive-xcode-build-settings-827c3ce4811c

Comment: Exactly the same as my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63061133/341994

Comment: @matt this does not work for me on Xcode 13.3 and M1 Mac

Comment: @EugeneGordin did you ever resolve it for M1 Mac? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @Patrick same for M2 any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I am adding an Apple Watch component to my existing iOS app using SwiftUI and I am also running into this warning in Xcode 12.0 (Yeah yeah, I need to update). In addition I was not getting the "Hello World!" to even show on the simulator.  I thought the LLDB warning was related to nothing showing on the watch simulator, however just wanted to point out that my Watch App will still compile if I first launch the iOS iPhone simulator.  Then launch the Watch Simulator after that.  Here are some screenshots if you are in the same boat.

[image: First select and run your iOS Simulator]

[image: Then select and run your Watch Simulator]